# NDSolve solution does not satisfy boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear

I am trying to solve a 1st order non-linear ODE

```
W[y]*W'[y] + W[y]*v + Fnum == 0 /. v -> 10

Fnum = 0.05 - 1.66667 y + (270.27 y)/(1 + 270.27 y) - (660. y)/(1 + 1666.67 y)
```

The function Fnum has three zeros. two of them are at y=StartY and y=EndY.

```
In[1]:= StartY = 0.00021578513459560855`;

In[2]:= EndY = 0.3870868735615052`;

In[3]:= Fnum = 0.05 - 1.66667 y + (270.27 y)/(1 + 270.27 y) - (660. y)/(1 + 
 1666.67 y)

Out[3]= 0.05 - 1.66667 y + (270.27 y)/(1 + 270.27 y) - (660. y)/(1 + 1666.67 y)

In[4]:= Fnum /. y -> StartY

Out[4]= 2.62289*10^-9

In[5]:= Fnum /. y -> EndY

Out[5]= -5.10119*10^-7
```

My boundary condition is W[y=StartY] == 0. However, if it set this NDSolve gives an error

```
s = NDSolve[{W[y]*W'[y] + W[y]*v + Fnum == 0 /. v -> 10, 
W[StartY] == 0 /. v -> 10}, W, {y, StartY, EndY}];
```

> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered. >>
>
> NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at y ==    0.00021578513459560855`. >>

I am guessing this happens because Mathematica cannot solve W[y]' at y=StratY

```
W'[y] = -v + Fum[y]/W[y] ~ -v + 0/0.
```

So, I am now trying to find W'[y=StartY] analytically by expanding Fnum near y=StartY and I find that W'[y=StartY]=dW. I show here only that my solution satisfies the differential equation with Fnum[StartY]=0 and boundary condition W[StartY=0]:

```
In[8]:= Slope = Coefficient[Normal[Chop[Series[Fnum, {y, StartY, 1}]]], y, 1]

Out[8]= -117.385

In[13]:= dW  = (Sqrt[v^2 - 4*Slope] - v)/2;

In[14]:= Solve[W*dW + W*v + Fnum == 0 /. {y -> StartY, v -> 10}, W]

Out[14]= {{W -> -1.54903*10^-10}}
```

Now I go back to NDSolve and I am trying W'[StartY] = dW as boundary condition

```
s = NDSolve[{W[y]*W'[y] + W[y]*v + Fnum == 0 /. v -> 10, W'[StartY] == (Sqrt[v^2 - 4*Slope] - v)/2 /. v -> 10}, W, {y, StartY, EndY}]
```

I get the following error:

> NDSolve::icordinit: The initial values for all the dependent variables are not explicitly specified. NDSolve will attempt to find consistent initial conditions for all the variables. >>
>
> NDSolve::icres: NDSolve has computed initial values that give a zero residual for the differential system, but some components are different from those specified. If you need them to be satisfied, giving explicit initial values to all dependent variables is recommended. >>
>
> NDSolve::ndsz: At y == 0.0854996004928462`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. >>

In spite of the errors, NDsolve does manage to find a solution. However, NDSolve does find a solution which with W[StartY]=1, which is not consistent.

```
In[15]:= Evaluate[W[StartY] /. s]

Out[15]= {1.}
```

What am I doing wrong? 
What do the error mean? 
Why NDSolve finds a solution which is not consistent with my boundary conditions?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: I formatted your question for you this time. Please learn how to do it for your nxt question. Thanks.

Comment: The styling of your question can be improved. Please take the time to read the [markdown help page](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help). You'll better communicate your problem when you use the right formatting.

Comment: You use Slope without ever assigning it a constant numeric value. Think of trying to do a simple manual Euler's approximation of f'[x]=Slope when I won't tell you what the value of Slope is. But even when I assign some constant value to Slope, there still appear to be warning messages and those almost always must be understood and fixed before any sensible result can be had

Comment: If `W == 0`, then `Fnum == 0` for the DE to be satisfied. But it isn't at `y -> StartY`.  (BTW, it's good practice to avoid beginning your own functions and variables with a capital.)

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Michael E2 : W==0 an Fnum==0 at StartY. Please have a look at the code

Comment: I re-formatted my questions, please have a look again. I hope it is clearer.

Comment: @user22375 (You need to put a @ in front of names for the person to get pinged.)  According to your own code Fnum is not equal to zero: `In[4]:= Fnum /. y -> StartY`, `Out[4]= 2.62289*10^-9`.  Execute `2.62289*10^-9 == 0` to check.  (Another side point: It will encourage more users to try out your code if they can copy and paste it in *Mathematica* without editing it.  The In and Out tags make it inconvenient. A convention many follow is to put output in comments.)

Comment: @user22375, to obtain the slope of W at StartY, I believe that the entire equation should be expanded about StartY, not just Fnum.  Doing so gives `slope^2+10 slope-117.385`, with values, `{-16.9325,6.93251}`. Next solve the equation starting at `StartY+d` with `W[StartY + d] == d slope` with d some small number.  Unfortunately, NDSolve believes that the equation is stiff, which surprises me.  I tried this with both values of slope and d as large as 0.1.  In any case, this may give you a start.  Good luck.

Answer (score 6):

The problem with NDSolve methods is that (as far as I know) it always check boundary points. And this a problem, as you noted. I would recommend you to look at this [wonderful approach](http://blog.wolfram.com/2013/07/09/using-mathematica-to-simulate-and-visualize-fluid-flow-in-a-box/). I adapted it to your problem below

```
v = 10;
eq = (W[y]*W'[y] + 
    W[y]*v + (0.05 - 
      1.66667 y + (270.27 y)/(1 + 270.27 y) - (660. y)/(1 + 
         1666.67 y)));
Fnum[y_] := 
  0.05 - 1.66667 y + (270.27 y)/(1 + 270.27 y) - (660. y)/(1 + 
      1666.67 y);
startY = 0.00021578513459560855`;
endY = 0.3870868735615052`;
pts = 500;
ygrid = Range[startY, endY, 1/(pts - 1)];
dwdy = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[1, ygrid, 
    "DifferenceOrder" -> 8]["DifferentiationMatrix"] ;
varsW = Table[Unique[w$], {Length[ygrid]}];
eqns = varsW*(dwdy.varsW) + varsW*v + Fnum[ygrid];
eqns[[1]] = varsW[[1]]; (* boundary condition W[StartY]\[Equal]0 *)

sol = varsW /. FindRoot[eqns, Thread[{varsW, 1/2}]]; 
Wsol = Interpolation[Transpose[{ygrid, sol}], 
   InterpolationOrder -> 2];
```

And here are plots. The solution

```
Plot[Wsol[y], {y, startY, endY}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: solution]

and the error

```
Plot[eq /. W -> Wsol, {y, startY, endY}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: error plot]

I noticed that increasing DifferenceOrder gives better results. You can also enlarge the grid itself.

Comment: this is a very elegant approach.  Because `Fnum` varies rapidly near `startY`, `W'` is large there, and your error estimate also is large there, solving the equation on a very fine mesh, say `10.^-5`, over the region `{startY,0.02}` may have merit.

Answer (score 5):

In an earlier comment, I observed that `NDSolve` found the equation to be stiff, even when the calculation was begun a short distance `d` from `StartY`. Because the third root of `Fnum` is `0.000797339`, `d` must be quite small, say, 0.0001.  However, even with this choice of `d`, `NDSolve` promptly stops because the equation is stiff.  It turns out, however, that `NDSolve` can solve the equation with the choice `v -> 11.3` (or larger) with the corresponding negative `slope` value, `-17.8691`. (The corresponding positive `slope`, `6.56913`, leaves the equation stiff.) The solution is

[image: Solution of W for v=11.3]

Solutions for smaller values of `v` can be obtained by a change of variables, `W -> -Sqrt[q]`.  (Choosing the positive root is equivalent to choosing the negative value of `slope`, which leaves the equation stiff.)  As one would expect, the resulting solution for `v -> 11.3` is the square of the curve above.

For `v -> 10.0`, `q` is complex:

[image: Solution of q for v=10]

The negative `Sqrt` of this curve is the desired result.

**Origin of complex-valued solution**

A blow-up of the figure just above at small `y` helps to explain why some solutions are complex-valued.

[image: q[y] for v=10 and very small y]

The solution vanishes at approximately `y=.0052497`, just as the solution does at `StartY`. However, here, `Fnum` does not vanish too.  Consequently, the leading terms in `q` in the vicinity of this zero are `0.544893(.0052497-y) + 14.7634(.0052497-y)^(3/2)`, as can be demonstrated by direct substitution. Thus, although the solution is continuously differentiable at `y=.0052497`, it has a branch point there, giving rise to the abrupt onset of complex values.  Incidentally, it is this zero, and not the one at `StartY`, that prevents a straightforward solution for `W` using `NDSolve`.

**v=0 analytical solution**

The equation can be solved analytically for `v->0`, yielding the following expression for `q=W^2`.

```
0.037919170215639376 + y*(-1.3080015839968322 + 1.66667*y) - 0.0004751980992057023*Log[0.0005999988000024 + y] + 
 0.007400007400007398*Log[0.0037000037000037003 + y]
```

This analytical solution may be useful in evaluating numerical solution methods for the equation. As shown in the plot below, it is negative almost everywhere, indicating that `W` is complex.  (`q` is positive only in the region `{StartY, 0.0015}`.)

[image: v=0 analytical solution]